# Connecting LED to GPIO pin without using jumper wire

Tags: gpio

Can I use ordinary wire and wind it on a GPIO pin instead of using a jumper wire to test an LED? Will it damage my Pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be fine.

Just be sure not to short out any adjacent pins as you wrap the wire around the pin.

For that reason it will be FAR SAFER to attempt this with the power OFF.

Answer (score -1):

Judging from your question, it seems that you are not an expert on circuits. So, to be on the safe side, use jumpers only.